# Mobile Events with attributes are not received (Android SDK)

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, event-monitoring

I am using the SalesForce Marketing Cloud Android SDK to track some events which seem to work unless we specify any attributes.

We've double checked that in the Filter Definition in the Web console the option is "Any of the criteria occurs" and not "None".

Here is the code we are using ("event_name", "attribute_name" and "attribute_value" have been replaced but the values correspond to the definition we've uploaded to the console).

```
 val attributes = mapOf("attribute_name" to "attribute_value")
 val sfmcEvent = EventManager.customEvent("event_name", attributes)
 SFMCSdk.track(sfmcEvent)
```

In the logs I can see that something is sent, but on the web console 0 events are recorded.

```
~$EventManager - Publishing events: CustomEvent( event_name ) to subscriber: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration.d@343590e
~$EventManager - Publishing events: CustomEvent( event_name ) to subscriber: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.events.c@f10f013
```